# Can external API content be added to Rest API in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is it possible to fetch data from an external API, and put them inside of WordPress REST API?

For example, schema would look like this:

```
 $api = 'https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents';

 $json_data = file_get_contents($api);

 $response_data = json_decode($json_data);

 $user_data = $response_data->data;

 $user_data = array_slice($user_data,0,20);

 foreach($user_data as $agent) {

    $sendToRest = $agent->displayIcon);
    array_push($sendToRest,$restArray);
 }
```

This is the logic that I came up with, but I don't know if this is okay or not, but you get the point :)

Comment: _Everything is ok in tech as long as it doesn't error out, doesn't hang the system, client doesn't have any complaints_. lol !

Comment: Hahaha, that is true, i just wanted some professional opinion for this :) @nice_dev

Comment: IMO, this is fine by me. Just make sure the `allow_url_fopen` setting is always set in your server. If you wish to switch the server in the coming future, this would need to be taken care of.

Comment: If at all possible, you should probably cache those external API results on your end - instead of making that external API request again and again each time something is requested from _your_ REST API.

Comment: @nice_dev Thank you, and will check on the server with Devops if this is set :)

Comment: @CBroe thats what i was going to do :) Cache all pics, or just cache the link to pictures, and upload them to some cdn, because i also need to convert them to Webp :)